# MPI: Local and non-local calls

Tags: mpi

I want to know what exactly are the two, and how they are different. What are the advantage or disadvantage of the two types of calls? Really appreciate using some small example code.

Answer (score 1):

These are detailed, e.g., in here: http://www.netlib.org/utk/papers/mpi-book/node14.html

It's not really proper to talk about advantages of either. They are for different purposes. An example of a local call MPI_Comm_rank, since it doesn't need input from other processes and an example of a non-local call is MPI_Send, since it will have to communicate with some other process that will recieve the message.